# The reducer does not transmit the initialState

Tags: reactjs, redux

[image]

The `this.props` does not have the `loading`, `error` key. 
Why?

My code on :

https://github.com/jiexishede/react-redux-demo01

You can fork it and pull request.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would highly encourage watching https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux as well

Comment: @AndyRay Thank you very much. I will ask questions according to the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't pass them in your `mapStateToProps` function

https://github.com/jiexishede/react-redux-demo01/blob/0c1407935cd6c461705d6ca37f3e33484afac327/src/views/Home.js#L8-L10

This should be something like:

```
@connect(state => {
    return {
        articleList: state.home.list.articleList,
        loading: state.home.list.loading,
        error: state.home.list.error,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set up your component to receive updates from your store. Your component won't know that the reducer has updated the state. Check out the code below:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as Redux from 'react-redux'; // Import redux
import Preview from './Preview'

class PreviewList extends  Component {
  static propTypes = {
    loading:React.PropTypes.bool,              //  注意 bushi PropTypes.bool,  前面要价 React
    error:React.PropTypes.bool,
    articleList: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object),
    loadArticles: React.PropTypes.func
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.loadArticles();
  }

  render(){
    const { loading, error, articleList } = this.props;
    if(error){
      return <p className="message">)0ops, something is wrong. </p>
    }
    if(loading){
      return <p className="message">Loading....</p>
    }

    // return this.props.articleList.map(item => (
    //     <Preview {...item} key={item.id}/>
    // ))

    return (
        <div>
          {articleList.map(item => {
            return <Preview {...item} key={item.id} push={this.props.push} />
          })}
        </div>
    );

  }
}

// Connect your component to your store and
// receive updates from your previewList reducer:
export default Redux.connect(state => {
    return {
        loading: state.previewList.loading,
        error: state.previewList.error,
        articleList: state.previewList.articleList
    };
})(PreviewList);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not connecting your component to the redux store. You need to install the react-redux package then use it's connect function to connect your component to the store like the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Preview from './Preview';
import { loadArticles } from './PreviewListRedux';

class PreviewList extends  Component {
  static propTypes = {
    loading:React.PropTypes.bool,      
    error:React.PropTypes.bool,
    articleList: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object),
    loadArticles: React.PropTypes.func
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.loadArticles();
  }

  render(){
    if (!this.props.loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    const { loading, error, articleList } = this.props;
    if(error){
      return <p className="message">)0ops, something is wrong. </p>
    }
    if(loading){
      return <p className="message">Loading....</p>
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {articleList.map(item => {
          return <Preview {...item} key={item.id} push={this.props.push} />
        })}
      </div>
    );
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    loading: state.list.loading,
    error: state.list.error,
    articleList: state.list.articleList
  }
};

export  default  connect(mapStateToProps, { loadArticles })(PreviewList);
```

Also, your code needs some major restructuring, it's really difficult to read through it and see how the different pieces are connected together.